# Cosa significa "essere sotto paga"?

Tags: meaning

Sto leggendo la commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi). L'espressione "sotto paga" che appare nel titolo si trova anche all'interno del testo, per esempio in questo brano:

> Dei tranvieri e operai del Comune che stavano manifestando lì fuori per via del contratto di lavoro che da tre anni non veniva rinnovato. «Calma! Calma! Cos’è questo cagasotto, ’sta paura che vi prende della polizia? Perdio! Siete nel vostro diritto di pagare quello che è giusto! Questo è come uno sciopero, anzi, è meglio di uno sciopero perché negli scioperi ci rimettiamo sempre la paga noi operai... invece questo finalmente è uno sciopero dove chi ci rimette è il padrone! Anzi, si fa di meglio: a zero ore anche lui!» (*Margherita ride e applaude*). «**Siamo sotto paga**, non si paga! **Sotto paga**! Non si paga! E questo vale per tutti i soldi che ci avete rubato fra lire ed euro in anni e anni che veniamo qui a fare la spesa!» E via che se ne vanno carichi di roba!

Le altre volte in cui appare l'espressione "sotto paga" sono semplicemente in bocca di donne che gridano "Sotto paga! Non si paga!", quindi non aggiungono contesto al passo sopra citato.

La mia domanda è: cosa significa "essere sotto paga"? Avere uno stipendio troppo esiguo? Ho cercato alla voce "paga" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione. Una ricerca su Google, però, mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un'espressione che si usa.

---

**Aggiornamento:**

Più avanti nel libro, in queste parole pronunciate da un appuntato della polizia, appare l'espressione "lavorare sottopaga", con "sottopaga" scritto attaccato:

> Ma che privilegiato! **Lavoriamo sottopaga**, gli straordinari gratis, in galera se scioperiamo, e al camposanto con un buco nella testa senza sapere per chi né perché! Privilegiati! (*Cambia tono*) Se si va avanti di questo passo, può anche darsi che uno di questi giorni le capiti di venire a sapere che dei poliziotti si sono rifiutati di andare a fare i pestaggi per i padroni... anzi, che si sono magari buttati dall’altra parte!

Answer (score 1):

In questo articolo de Il sole 24 Ore *[Sotto paga, non si paga!» di Dario Fo](https://st.ilsole24ore.com/art/SoleOnLine4/Tempo%20libero%20e%20Cultura/2009/04/fo-sotto-paga-npn-si-paga.shtml)* viene data una chiave di lettura del titolo:

> Testimone prezioso di una generazione di straordinari artisti in via
> di estinzione, coscienza superiore da premio Nobel, ideologo libero,
> maestro indiscusso, Fo come sempre centra in pieno il bersaglio.
> Sembra scritto oggi il profetico testo, la crisi economica, i nuovi
> poveri, i prezzi alle stelle, le fabbriche che mietono vittime
> operaie, animano il plot della commedia. **L'occasione nasce dalle
> peripezie di due strampalate coppie alle prese, ieri come oggi, con il
> salario e i conti che non tornano mai.**

Siccome gli operai e in generale i lavoratori sono sfruttati e pagati poco, da qui il sotto paga, allora si danno vita a tutta una serie di cosiddetti espropri proletari, ovvero non pagare la spesa al supermercato o, al limite, pagarla il giusto, cioè compatibilmente al potere di acquisto del proprio salario.

Comment: Quindi l'espressione è equivalente a "Essere sottopagato", ovvero essere pagato poco (meno di quanto tollerabile)?

Comment: Esattamente. Anch'io avevo inizialmente interpretato _essere sotto paga_ come essere salariato, stipendiato, ma nel contesto dell'opera teatrale significa essere sfruttato, sottopagato.

Comment: Si può aggiungere che questa espressione probabilmente serve a fare la rima e scandire lo slogan ;)

Comment: Tutto questo l'ho capito dalla lettura del testo della commedia. La mia domanda riguarda soltanto il significato dell'espressione "essere sotto paga". Da quello che hai scritto, debbo interpretare che significa "essere pagato poco" (cioè, più  o meno quello che dicevo nella domanda)? Per esempio, quando su [questo forum](https://forum.everyeye.it/invision/index.php/topic/757148-battlefield-1-topic-ufficialeps4/page-47) si afferma "A quanto pare pare tutti gli yuotuber più famosi di battlefield sono sotto paga di...", questo significa che questi "yuotuber" [sic] sono pagati poco?

Comment: @Charo No, significa che sono pagati da qualcuno per i loro servigi. In questo caso è il contesto che determina il significato specifico.

Comment: Non avevo letto il commento di @RiccardoDeContardi: stavo scrivendo il mio allo stesso tempo. (Forse ho avuto bisogno di 6 minuti per scriverlo).

Comment: Vediamo se ho capito bene: "essere sotto paga" di solito significa ricevere uno stipendio da qualcuno, ma nel contesto del brano significa essere pagato poco. È così?

Comment: @Charo Per me no. Ho letto il brano e dice _"meglio di uno sciopero perché negli scioperi ci rimettiamo sempre la paga noi operai..."_ (nel senso che se scioperi non prendi -tutto o in parte- lo stipendio).  Poi dicono _"Siamo sotto paga"_ (In questo momento siamo pagati, non ci viene tolto lo stipendio), _"Non si paga"_ (né per scioperare, né per quanto intuisco per portare via le cose... _"E via che se ne vanno carichi di roba!"_).

Comment: @Hastur: Forse hai ragione. Tuttavia, Joseph Farrell, che ha fatto questa [traduzione all'inglese](https://books.google.es/books?hl=it&id=YY_6NNco8yoC&q=underpaid#v=onepage&q=underpaid&f=false) della commedia  di Fo, ha capito che "sotto paga" significhi "underpaid".